# how to replace a dom node with new node?

Tags: java

I want to replace a existing Dom node with a new node I have created.I am implementing this as

```
String messageBody=" <imgGroup><img src="src" width="width" height="height" alt="alt" type="type" orient="orient"/></imgGroup>"
File file=new File("doc.xml");
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
                doc = docBuilder.parse(file);
               Element node =  DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(messageBody.getBytes()))
                .getDocumentElement();
               System.out.println(node.getClass());
               doc.getDocumentElement().replaceChild((Node)node, doc.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild());
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I am getting an run time  error 
`WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR:` A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.

Can any one suggest how to do it in different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to adopt the node by the new document, calling [`Document.adoptNode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#adoptNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29). Note that `adoptNode()` in itself won't add the node anywhere in the target document, just allow you to add it to the DOM tree. You still have to call `replaceChild()` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This one took me a bit of time to understand, too.  At least the error message is helpful and the API provides clues as well.

WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR means that your code is working with two different DOMs.  The first DOM is the "existing" one.  This is probably the one that you want to add the new node into.  The second DOM is the "new" one - the one that is created when a new node is created.

You can import the new node into the existing document.  Importing does not add the new node to the existing document though; importing will create a new node that has the same document owner as the existing DOM.  You'll then need to add the new node to the existing document through a call like append or replace or whatever the desired operation is.

I don't have example code in front of me, but if I think you can use a debugger to compare the ownerDocument field for an element in the existing DOM and the new element.